# Mysql query giving incorrect values

Tags: mysql, join

When this SQL query is executed it gives incorrect value, please advise

```
select
    sum(cash_management.cash_in),
    sum(cash_management.cash_out),
    sum(cash_management.pay_in),
    sum(cash_management.pay_out),
    sum(cash_management.cash_declared),
    sum(cash_management.cashin_drawer),
    sum(order_master.order_quantity*order_master.order_item_price),
    cash_management.date,
    order_master.cashier_name,
    cash_management.cashier_name 
from cash_management inner join order_master 
where cash_management.cashier_name=order_master.cashier_name   
and date(date)='2015-02-19' 
and date(order_time)='2015-02-19'
```

Comment: Data you are starting with?  Expected output?  Or how else we should know what's wrong here?

Comment: Formatting the code would not hurt either. How do you even read this code?

Comment: This might be the classic problem of aggregates being inflated due to a JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what data you are starting with in each table, what is being produced and what is wrong/what you expected - I can only make some general observations to help you:

1)Code Formatting - Format your code better, use table aliases to shorten your code or at least tidy it up a bit.  You will find it easier to read and therefore debug.

2)At a guess, could it be your WHERE caluse at fault?  If this is a sales ledger, are "date" and "order_time" always going to be the same date?  If a record is inserted into a table and then a field is updated, you may find that the double WHERE is excluding records that you want included.

3)Since you have a join going on - do the required records (an order master record and a corresponding cash management record) exist on both tables?

As I said, no data and no examples so I can't help - but these are my starters for 10.

Comment: I've reformatted the OP's code.  Fazer comment was accurate, though - it was illegible.